# Finding non-duplicate numbers and duplicate numbers from a list?

Tags: python

I'm new to coding and struggling a bit with this one. Can anyone show me how to write the pseudocode for a program that finds the non-duplicate numbers and duplicate numbers (as simply as possible.)

thanks!
**

```
input:**

56
75
1
46
100
97
75
46
46

Output:

Non-duplicates:
56
1
100
97

Duplicates:
75
46
```

I tried :

```
list = [56, 75, 1, 46, 100, 97, 75, 46, 46] 
dupes = [] 
unique = [] 

for x in list: if x not in dupes: dupes.append(x) else: unique.append(x) print(dupes) print(unique)
```

However, I beleive there might be a more elegant solution (that matches the output.) The exercise I took this from was about sets. I'm not sure if that's too relevant!

Thanks

Comment: This logic is not sufficient to solve the problem.  When a number is first encountered, you don't yet know if it should belong in the unique list or the dupes list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `count()` method:

```
lst = [56, 75, 1, 46, 100, 97, 75, 46, 46]
dupes = []
unique = []

for x in lst:
    if lst.count(x) == 1:
        unique.append(x)
    elif x not in dupes:
        dupes.append(x)

print('Non-duplicates:', *unique, sep='\n',)
print()
print('Duplicates:', *dupes, sep='\n')
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you're working on sets currently I'd suggest using sets, you could try something like this:

```
data = [56, 75, 1, 46, 100, 97, 75, 46, 46] 
dupes = set() 
unique = set()

for num in data:
    if num in unique:
        dupes.add(num)
        continue  # this isn't needed but it bypasses the extra addition
    unique.add(num)
     
unique -= dupes
        
print(unique)
print(dupes)
```

---

```
{56, 1, 100, 97}
{75, 46}
```

If you'd like to use `collections.Counter` you could do the following for example:

```
from collections import Counter

data = [56, 75, 1, 46, 100, 97, 75, 46, 46] 

elements = Counter(set(data))
dupes = Counter(data) - elements
unique = elements - dupes

print(*unique)
print(*dupes)
```

---

```
1 97 100 56
75 46
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Counter` from `collections`, then check when the count is more than one:

```
from collections import Counter
xs = [1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 6]
c = Counter(xs)
uniques = [x for x in c if c[x] == 1]
multiples = [x for x in c if c[x] != 1]
print(uniques, multiples)
```

You can optimize this to be a single loop over the `Counter` if necessary.